# performance wise, should I use AVAudioEngine for multiple sound effects yes or no?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

Performance-wise, is it better to use an `AVAudioPlayerNode` instance with

A.  one `AVAudioEngine` instance, to which I connect multiple sound effects to its mixer

B. a separate instance of `AVAudioEngine` for each sound effect?

The reason I'm using AVAudioEngine is because I'm doing some audio processing with AVAudioUnitVaryspeed, but each sound effect can be (and is) independent, so I was wondering if anyone knows what's best?

Is it OK to have an AVAudioEngine and its nodes for each effect or should I manage a single engine instance and connect / disconnect nodes as sounds play?

Comment: Premature optimization? If you're not having an actual problem, do this the easiest most natural way.

Comment: I still would like to know whether someone else has faced this problem, because I want to code this audio library the best way possible. No need to downvote 

Comment: What I'm saying is that your question doesn't contain any "problem".

Comment: @matt I disagree, this is a basic but valid question about an AVFoundation best practice.

Comment: @Eric Well I think the intention is obvious — AVAudioEngine is designed to have just one of them running at a time. My response to the OP is to ask why that's problematic.

Comment: If that was the intention/recommendation then you'd expect it to be a singleton (like in `NotificationCenter`, `LocationManager`, or `UserDefaults`). But that's not the case, because there are legitimate use cases where you have more than one `AVAudioEngine` running. And since the `AVAudioEngine` docs alone don't make it clear when to use a single instance vs. multiple, OP's question is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage a single `AVAudioEngine` instance to which all your effects and player are connected, and connect/disconnect nodes as sounds play.

Having multiple `AVAudioEngine` instances isn't a problem because of the performance overhead, but because it'll become too complicated to manage them all in real time, having them all respond to `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification` and `AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification`, keeping all the players in sync, testing each one of them using `renderOffline`, and so on.

I recommend you watch WWDC 2014 Session 502 - AVAudioEngine in Practice, for a good introduction to this API. One of the use cases they bring up is very similar to yours – and they use just one `AVAudioEngine` instance :-)